# Request.Form for DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, forms

I have on my view:

```
</td>
  <td class="span-8 last">
    <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="Traslado_Movimiento_UbicacionFuncional_Id">Ubicaci&#243;n Funcional</label>
    </div>  
     <div class="editor-field">  
       <select id="Traslado_Movimiento_UbicacionFuncional_Id"                 name="Traslado.Movimiento.UbicacionFuncional_Id"><option value=""> -- Seleccione -- </option>
          </select>
    </div>                        
</td>
```

And I want to get the selected value on the select.

On my controller I wrote:

```
string selected = Request.Form["Traslado_Movimiento_UbicacionFuncional_Id"];
```

But selected is always NULL....

Please, help!

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the input's `name`, which contains `.`s.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!... Now, that returns the value, there's a way to get the text?

Comment: No; that's how HTML forms work.  You should make sure that everything you need is in the `value`.

Comment: Please elaborate with an example

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you would need to add the `runat="server"` attribute. But why are you using the HTML select control if you want to use this from server code? It seems to make a lot more sense to use the ASP.NET combobox.